# How to get next cucumber step after passed if it is failed

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have `AfterStep` hook which can give me a step name. But it gives only name of passed step.

```
AfterStep do |result, step|
  puts step.name
end
```

How to get next cucumber step after passed if next is failed?
Or how to get name of failed step?

Maybe somehow to calculate step position and take another one?

Any ideas?
I am sure that it is possible because we can see failed step name in error log.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found. We can use `scenario.exception.backtrace`
It will return an array with step name. And then just get need element from array.
But, maybe there is something else which can give that failed step?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `AfterStep` is not called at all is simple: it is treated as a simple step and is [just appended](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/0161920e5dde15161d74091ffb3ac04aef0b1938/lib/cucumber/runtime/step_hooks.rb#L11) to the list of steps. Hence, as soon as any of steps fails, `scenario` is stopped and `AfterStep` never gets called. I would consider it being a bug in `cucumber-ruby`.

As a workaround, one might use `After` hook:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    puts "Failed: " << scenario.marshal_dump[2].first.source.inspect
  end
end
```